# phpmyadmin showing php code 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to set up phpmyadmin on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Dedicated Server but seem to be running into an issue of the page displaying plain PHP Code.

I've searched around and tried some suggestions but nothing seems to be working.

I am running the following PHP Version

```
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend 
Technologies
```

and this is what I get (it's not the full page of what I get, I can post the full page if you need me to):

```
<?php
    /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */
use PMA\libraries\RecentFavoriteTable;

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * display Git revision if requested
 */
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',
    'collation_connection',
    'db',
    'table'
);
foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);

/*
 * Black list of all scripts to which front-end must submit data.
 * Such scripts must not be loaded on home page.
 *
 */
$target_blacklist = array (
    'import.php', 'export.php'
);

// If we have a valid target, let's load that script instead
if (! empty($_REQUEST['target'])
    && is_string($_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! preg_match('/^index/', $_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $target_blacklist)
    && in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $goto_whitelist)
) {
    include $_REQUEST['target'];
    exit;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['ajax_request']) && ! empty($_REQUEST['access_time'])) {
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable the php7.2 module:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

restart the service (the command above reminds you)

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

and then the phpmyadmin page appears as it should